# Select from one MySQL database table and Batch Insert in another database table using Java || Batch Insertion not Working

Tags: java, mysql, sql-insert

This batch Insertion is not working (slow),
if i put `ps1.executeBatch();` outside the `while` loop , in that case batch is working but only last record is being inserted.

```
public static void insert(){
        try{
            //for 1st DB
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");

            // for 2nd DB
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");

            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            con2.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table2 (data) VALUES(?)");

            PreparedStatement ps = con2.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table1");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                x++;
                System.out.println(x + " Inserted");
                
                ps1.setInt(1,rs.getString("data"));

                ps1.addBatch();
                ps1.executeBatch();
            }
            con.commit();
            con2.commit();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try moving `executeBatch` out of the body of the `while` loop.

Comment: You copy rows from-to tables in the same database. So copying via client makes no sense. Create one query `INSERT .. SELECT` and execute it - MySQL will perform needed action without any additional java code.

Comment: @AndreiOdegov "tried moving executeBatch out of the body of the while loop" but the problem is ,only last record of table1 is inserted into table2

Comment: @Akina sorry, yes it should be "con" , corrected it

Comment: This code is working fine , when i insert the record to the table in local DB , but when i perform the same action in 2 different Databases (which are not in local )it's slow , execution time is similar to ```ps1.executeUpdate()```

Comment: *but when i perform the same action in 2 different Databases* On the same MySQL instance? if not then this is not surprise - the most part of time is needed for network data transfer, and this is a case when batch operation will save a lot of time.

Comment: Show us the generated SQL.